# Close all popovers ng-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular, popover, ng-bootstrap

I have few stacked popovers getting called on certain user action, Now once the user is on the last popover I would like to close all of them,
Is there a way in ng-bootstrap to close all the popover at once.

I did try closing the popovers by taking the DOM element and closing it, but since I have a bunch of them I thought of checking if there is a better way of closing all the active popovers.

Below is the popover code -

```
<ng-template #popover1>
  <ul>
    <li>Element1</li>
    <li>Element2</i></li>
    <li [ngbPopover]="popover2"
        [autoClose]="'outside'"
        popover-is-open="false">
    Element3
    </li>
  </ul>
</ng-template>




  <ng-template #popover2>
      <ul>
        <li>Element1</li>
        <li>Element2</i></li>
        <li [ngbPopover]="popover2"
            [autoClose]="'outside'"
            popover-is-open="false">
        Element3
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-template>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are already having the Directive `ngbPopover`.  You can get all children by this and can call close method on it.

Comment: If I call close method it on the parent level it doesnt close the popups.

Comment: Please replicate your issue in stackblitz. That will help to get the fix quicker.

Comment: @user334011 did you get a fix for this?